# Lucene 4.1 is ignoring FieldType.tokenized = false

Tags: java, lucene

I'm using Lucene 4.1 to index keyword/value pairs, where the keywords and values are not real words - i.e., they are voltages, settings, that should not be analyzed or tokenized.  e.g. $P14R / 16777216.  (this is FCS data for any Flow Cytometrists out there)

For indexing, I create a FieldType with indexed = true, stored = true, and **tokenized = false**. These mimic the ancient Field.Keyword from Lucene 1, for which I have the book.  :-)  I even freeze the fieldType.

I see these values in the debugger.  I create the document and index.

When I read the index and document and look at the Fields in the debugger, I see all my fields.  The names and fieldsData look correct.  However, the FieldType is wrong.  It shows indexed = true, stored = true, and **tokenized = true**.  The result is that my searches (using a TermQuery) do not work.

How can I fix this?  Thanks.

p.s. I am using a KeywordAnalyzer in the IndexWriterConfig.  I'll try to post some demo code later, but it's off to my real job for today.  :-)

DEMO CODE:

```
public class LuceneDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Directory lDir = new RAMDirectory();
    Analyzer analyzer = new KeywordAnalyzer();
    IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_41, analyzer);
    iwc.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE);
    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(lDir, iwc);

    // BTW, Lucene, anyway you could make this even more tedious???
    // ever heard of builders, Enums, or even old fashioned bits?
    FieldType keywordFieldType = new FieldType();
    keywordFieldType.setStored(true);
    keywordFieldType.setIndexed(true);
    keywordFieldType.setTokenized(false);

    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new Field("$foo",  "$bar123", keywordFieldType));
    doc.add(new Field("contents",  "$foo=$bar123", keywordFieldType));
    doc.add(new Field("$foo2",  "$bar12345", keywordFieldType));

    Field onCreation = new Field("contents",  "$foo2=$bar12345", keywordFieldType);
    doc.add(onCreation);
    System.out.println("When creating, the field's tokenized is " + onCreation.fieldType().tokenized());
    writer.addDocument(doc);
    writer.close();

    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(lDir);
    Document d1 = reader.document(0);
    Field readBackField = (Field) d1.getFields().get(0);
    System.out.println("When read back the field's tokenized is " + readBackField.fieldType().tokenized());

    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

// exact match works
Term term = new Term("$foo", "$bar123" );
    Query query = new TermQuery(term);
    TopDocs results = searcher.search(query, 10);
    System.out.println("when searching for : " + query.toString() + "  hits = " + results.totalHits);

    // partial match fails
    term = new Term("$foo", "123" );
    query = new TermQuery(term);
    results = searcher.search(query, 10);
    System.out.println("when searching for : " + query.toString() + "  hits = " + results.totalHits);

    // wildcard search works
    term = new Term("contents", "*$bar12345" );
    query = new WildcardQuery(term);
    results = searcher.search(query, 10);
    System.out.println("when searching for : " + query.toString() + "  hits = " + results.totalHits);
    }
}
```

output will be:

```
When creating, the field's tokenized is false
When read back the field's tokenized is true
when searching for : $foo:$bar123  hits = 1
when searching for : $foo:123  hits = 0
when searching for : contents:*$bar12345  hits = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a [KeywordAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/KeywordAnalyzer.html) for the fields you don't want to tokenize.

If you need multiple analyzers (that is, if you have other fields that need tokenization), [PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper.html) is the way.

Comment: I am using a KeywordAnalyzer in the IndexWriterConfig.

Answer (score 1):

Lucene stores all tokens in **lower case** - hence, you need to convert your search strings to lower case first for non-tokenized fields.

Answer (score 0):

The demo code proves that the value for tokenized is different when you read it back.  Not sure if that is a bug or not.

But that isn't why the partial search doesn't work.  The partial search doesn't work cause Lucene doesn't do partial searches (unless you use Wildcard)  e.g. [Says so here in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786338/document-search-on-partial-words)

Been using Google so long I guess I didn't understand that.  :-)