# I want to search words like "AND" , "OR" , "NOT" in lucene but it doesn't find them

Tags: python, search, lucene, pylucene

Require help in lucene search
Working on lucene i have tried phrase search and term search both but not getting results.
These stop words cant be found in lucene index

Comment: Welcome to SO. In order for us to help you, please clarify your problem by showing some code. What have you tried so far? What do you mean by "not getting results"?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of examples of finding the Stopwords like `"AND", "OR", "NOT" in Lucene`.
Try the links below:

[Stopwords](http://ankitjain.info/ankit/2009/05/27/lucene-search-ignore-word-list/)

[Anagrams and Sub-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786338/document-search-on-partial-words)